Stepper motor turns unexpectedly slowly
I want to control a stepper motor using my esp32 and an USB connection. I seem to have some issue understanding why the stepper motor runs very slowly - I suspect it's because power to the motor is somehow provided through the ESP32 board?

Using this setup, and cautiously using very conservative current settings on the TMC2209 (ca 50-100mA), the stepper motor only turns very slowly.
Oberservations:


Using an external power supply, the motor spins according to expectation, pretty fast.
When I dis/reconnect the 20v supply from the pd power board to the TMC2209, it spins again, according to speed of external power supply, after initially turning slowly
providing power/ground to MS1/MS2 pins has no effect on this


Hardware)


Standard ESP32 devkit board with cp2101
the tmc2209 is V3 (with silly wrong labels) from here
the power is a pd trigger board from Aliexpress (seems to provide steady 20v)
the variable step down converter is this one


Software) For the TMC2209 library I'm using this example sketch using one UART cable.
Questions)

Why is the motor spinning faster with an external powersupply (directly attached to the TMC2209)?
What would be a better design / or what can be improved in this setup?
How do I not burn more ESP32 boards / Stepper drivers?

The code is this, from the examples
#include <TMC2209.h>

// This example will not work on Arduino boards without HardwareSerial ports,
// such as the Uno, Nano, and Mini.
//
// See this reference for more details:
// https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/
//
// To make this library work with those boards, refer to this library example:
// examples/UnidirectionalCommunication/SoftwareSerial

HardwareSerial & serial_stream = Serial2;
const int TX_PIN = 17;
const int RX_PIN = 16;
const long SERIAL_BAUD_RATE = 115200;

const int32_t RUN_VELOCITY = 10000;
const int32_t STOP_VELOCITY = 0;
const int RUN_DURATION = 2000;
const int STOP_DURATION = 1000;
// current values may need to be reduced to prevent overheating depending on
// specific motor and power supply voltage
const uint8_t RUN_CURRENT_PERCENT = 100;


// Instantiate TMC2209
TMC2209 stepper_driver;
bool invert_direction = false;

void setup()
{
//  stepper_driver.setup(serial_stream);
  stepper_driver.setup(serial_stream, SERIAL_BAUD_RATE, TMC2209::SERIAL_ADDRESS_0, RX_PIN, TX_PIN);
  stepper_driver.setRunCurrent(RUN_CURRENT_PERCENT);
  stepper_driver.enableCoolStep();
  stepper_driver.enable();
}

void loop()
{
  stepper_driver.moveAtVelocity(STOP_VELOCITY);
  delay(STOP_DURATION);
  if (invert_direction)
  {
    stepper_driver.enableInverseMotorDirection();
  }
  else
  {
    stepper_driver.disableInverseMotorDirection();
  }
  invert_direction = not invert_direction;

  stepper_driver.moveAtVelocity(RUN_VELOCITY);

  delay(RUN_DURATION);
}


to be honest, it is likely that it has something to do with the default values of the library, since if you initialize it properly, it turns slowly. But if you reset the power, then it works. It doesn't explain why it would work with an external power supply with same voltage that is provided at start though...

indeed this was a default value issue.
    stepper_driver.setMicrostepsPerStep(1);

or
    stepper_driver.setMicrostepsPerStep(8);

solved the issue. Unsure where to exact line of code is in the library that initializes the MicrostepsPerStep at 256, which gives extremely precise, yet slow movement - maybe this is also the tmc2209 or tmc2209 version I'm using.
